# How to select all values in drop down list by clicking a button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select all values in drop down list by clicking a button using jQuery in JavaScript?

Comment: think you might mean javascript...

Comment: I have updated the tags to read "JavaScript" in place of "Java" - these are two different languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('select').children('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Should do it. Of course you would need a `SELECT` element with attribute `multiple`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with plain multi-select lists and multi-select lists that have optgroups.

```
$("select option").attr("selected", "true");
```

Note: This is the HTML answer, for XHTML selected should equal "selected", rather than true.