# How to insert multiple selected values in database using Laravel

Tags: html, mysql, select, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel. I'm trying to insert multiple select values from listbox to a database table. This is the HTML of the select drop down I'm using:

```
<select name="tsubject[]" id="tsubject[]" multiple>
    <option value="0">select</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option 
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
</select>
```

My controller.php is

```
else{
    $teachers =new ForumTeacher(); 
    $teachers ->tsubject=Input::get('tsubject[]');
}
```

The error that occurs is as follows;

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tsubject' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `forum_teachers` (`tname`, `tmobile`, `ttype`, `tcls`, `tdivn`, `tsubject`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (NamithaP, 9876543211, normalteacher, 6, D, , 2015-02-12 09:09:16, 2015-02-12 09:09:16))
```

Comment: Please edit the question rather than posting an unreadable wall of code in comments.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your problem, with that poor informations, we can do more than asking questions...

Comment: srry...im trying to inset multiple values into database single row...Ihave a select box that contain 4 subjects.im select 3 subject using this select  code <select name="tsubject[]" id="tsubject[]" multiple><option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option 
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
</select> but i can not save into database(i want in database like this eg:english,hindi,maths).i dont know how to write code in controler.php page using multiple selete?

Comment: This is a great question.  Lots of examples on the Internet about how to insert a variable that is a string or num into a RDBM - it's simple - but basically no clear, good ones when that variable is an array as the result of a multi select form input.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a teacher table and subject table and you have many-to-many relationship and is linked in a pivot table 'subject_teacher'

In laravel it is easier to use of blade.

First in your controller you have to populate your subjects list

```
$subjectsList= Subjects::lists('subjecName','id');
//    $previousSelectedSubjects = some optional selected subjects to
return View::make('yourview')->with('subjectsList', $subjectsList)->with('previousSelectedSubjects ', $previousSelectedSubjects);
```

Then in your view use it like this:

```
    {{ Form::select('subjects[]', $subjectsList, $previousSelectedSubjects->lists('id'), array('multiple'=>'multiple'))}}
```

and in your controller, after posting data, use submitted data

```
 if (Input::has('subjects'))
    foreach(Input::get('subjects')as $subject)
    {
        $forumTeacher= new ForumTeacher; // I think this is your intermediat, pivot, table
        $forumTeacher->teacher_id= $id; // you should know how to find this id
        $forumTeacher->subject_id= $subject->id;        
        $forumTeacher->save();  
    }
```

If some thing is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: i have only one table tbl_subject , and i get the subject from this table also checkall function is done...im only want save(insert )this checked values into tbl_catrgory table in database. i think its similar function of selectall values insert into database.

Comment: Plz, reformulate your question again. you mentioned `else{
    $teachers =new ForumTeacher(); 
    $teachers ->tsubject=Input::get('tsubject[]');
}` and now you say category. I can't understand your situation.

Comment: oh srry....else{ $teachers =new ForumTeacher(); $teachers ->tsubject=Input::get('tsubject[]'); }    this for select all from listbox insert into  db..                           now i want checkall function...im checked 5 subject using checkall and  how to save (insert) this 5 subjects  into database table same field like this(eg:english,math,hindi,..)how to insert into it what is controller.php code....

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get your problem. I recommend you to forget about the code you wrote. Explain in pain English what you need exactly.

Comment: srry............... i have 5 subjects .im fetched from database  (table:subject)   to display webpage.and im create 5 checkbox to each subjects .im create  2 submit buttons ..1.checkall button and 2. submit button. then im click checkall button all checkboxes are checked(tik mark).then  i want im click submit button these 5 subjects are insert  to database (table:mark). like this (eg:english,math,hindi,..) what is the code in controller.php... sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Now u mention subjects, only. where do teachers take place in your scenario??

Answer (score 0):

As you are wanting to get the input use `$subjects = Input::get('tsubject');` forget about the [].

If you want them all in the same field, do the following;

```
$teachers =new ForumTeacher(); 
$teachers->tsubject = implode(',', Input::get('tsubject'));
$teachers->save();
```

Optionally, once you have the input you can do the following to insert for each of the subjects like so;

```
foreach ($subjects as $subject){
    $teachers = new ForumTeacher(); 
    $teachers->tsubject = $subject;
    $teachers->save();
}
```

This will create and save your data to your table.

### What I Recommend

By the looks of the query you are doing, it is not best practice to store multiple options in a single field. I think it would be best you set up a pivot table to handle the relationships between the teacher and subjects.

For example;

**Teacher Table Data** (without the tsubject field):
id, tname, tmobile, ttype, tcls, tdivn, updated_at, created_at
1, NamithaP, 9876543211, normalteacher, 6   ,     D, 2015-02-12 09:09:16, 2015-02-12 09:09:16

**Subject pivot Table data:**
id of NamithaP, id of Subject

**Subject table:**
Subject Id, Maths
Subject Id, English
....

You can read more about many to many relations ships [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many).

Comment: thank you ..............$teachers =new ForumTeacher(); 
$teachers->tsubject = implode(',', Input::get('tsubject')); this code working..

Comment: is it similar to  checkall values insert into database? im trying to checkall function eg:5 subject and corresponding checkbox.then  2 buttons 1.checkall ,2.submit... click a 1st button checkall checked all subjects..then clck submit button. i want allchecked values go to database....what to do????

Comment: Answer for that question found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656378/how-to-select-all-values-in-drop-down-list-by-clicking-a-button-using-jquery)

Comment: @chips if you have found the answer to your question please mark as an answer for others. I also recommend if you are storing multiple options in one field you normalise your database tables to use pivots. This is in the What i recommend section of the answer.